# Show that $C^{\infty}(M)$ equipped with sum and punctual product is a commutative ring

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to prove that $C^{\infty}(M)$,the space of function $f: M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{\infty}$, is a commutative ring under both punctual product ($f(C)\cdot g(C), C\subseteq M$, $C$ is an open set), and sum.

The definition of commutative ring tell us that that: $(C^{\infty}(M),+)$ need to be an abelian group; the multiplication is associative and distributive with respect to addition; the multiplication is commutative and has $1$ as identity element.

If $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$ then $f+g$ is again a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function; because both $f,g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which is also an abelian group under $+$,we have $f(C)+g(C)=g(C)+ f(C)$ $\forall C\subseteq M$. Considering $f,g, h\in C^{\infty}(M)$, we have that both $f\cdot (g+ h)$ and $f\cdot g +f\cdot h$ are in $C^{\infty}(M)$. Moreover, since $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring, $f(C)\cdot (g(C)+ h(C)) = f(C)\cdot g(C) +f(C)\cdot h(C)$ holds (associativity comes from that of $\mathbb{R}$).

The same holds for $f(C)\cdot g(C) = g(C)\cdot f(C)$, since $f(C)\cdot g(C)$ and $g(C)\cdot f(C)$ are in $C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is a commutative ring. The identity application
$I: M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $I(C)=1$ for all $C\in M$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$ is such that  $f(C)\cdot I(C)= I(C)\cdot f(C)$ for all $C\in M$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ (again, $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring), and hence is the identity for the punctual product.

Let me know if this is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Confised - why do you consider $f(C)+g(C)$ and $f(C)\cdot g(C)$ for $C\subseteq M$ isneatd of for $C\in M$?

Comment: Since you probably alrady know that the set of *all* functions from a non-empty set $M$ to $\bbb R$ form a commutative ring, it would also suffice to show that $C^\infty(M)$ is a subring, i.e., difference and product of smooth functions are smooth

Comment: for the first answer: ok because C is an element of M. About the second, I' assuming product, sum and difference returning C^{\infty} function. If I'm right, you're are suggesting me a more compact way for obtaining the same answer; mine is correct ?(I'not a mathematician so even "obvious" could not be obvious for me ).

Comment: *"obvious" facts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your arguments are correct.